# opencart admin session not working in localhost. it is redirecting to localhost/admin

Tags: opencart

I am using Opencart 2.3.0.2, and just installed in localhost and also created a database. during installation i gave username and password for admin. but admin side is not getting.
 when i write ther url localhost/mysitename/admin it is redirecting to localhost/admin..

Answer (score 1):

You need to open the .htaccess file and change the line that says where your eshop is installed.

By default is:

```
RewriteBase /
```

But in your case you need to change it to:

```
RewriteBase /mysitename/
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check .htaaccess file in the root folder. Open the file and make change in below line -

   RewriteBase /

Change the above line to below code -

```
RewriteBase /mysitename
```

2. In case the above does not work, please check the config.php file in root directory and /admin directory and check the HTTP_SERVER path. If the path is not correct then please correct the path of these files.

Hope it will help. Please feel free to ask in case of any query or issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `admin/config.php` file.  You want something like this:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://localhost:8888/YOURSITE/upload/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://localhost:8888/YOURSITE/upload/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://localhost:8888/YOURSITE/upload/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://localhost:8888/YOURSITE/upload/');
```

I'm assuming you're using MAMP/WAMP; if not, leave off the port number.